# I am trying to install styed-components but not working

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-install, styled-components, npm-package

I am trying to install styled-components but it's showing me error:
`npm ERR! Cannot read properties of null (reading 'edgesOut')`

My npm command:
`npm install styled-components npm ERR! Cannot read properties of null (reading 'edgesOut')`

The error output:
`npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\kumar\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-05-24T08_20_22_392Z-debug-0.log`

I installed NPM again and clear caches but not worked.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a dependency graph or how the npm tries to resolve the package deps.

You can try cleaning out the npm cache by running the command `npm cache clean --force`, then delete your *node_modules* folder, and *package.lock*.

Finally, run the installation command again, it should work. I hope it will!

Comment: I tried the installation with NPM and did not work. Tried it out with yarn and had no issue.